How to Read Joystick Input from Logitech Extreme 3D Pro in Python?
I'm working on a Python program to read inputs from a Logitech Extreme 3D Pro joystick. I am able to receive raw data from the joystick, but I'm struggling to correctly interpret the X and Y values from this data.
Problem:
I have raw data as shown in the attached image. From the array, each value represents a different key or axis, but I'm having trouble identifying which values correspond to X and Y axis movements. Specifically, I suspect that array[1] and array[2] are the X and Y values, but the readings are inconsistent and don't seem to correlate with the joystick movements.

Code:
import pywinusb.hid as hid
from time import sleep
from msvcrt import kbhit

def sample_handler(data):
    print("Raw data: {}".format(data))

# Known Logitech vendor_id
vendor_id = 0x046D  # Logitech

# Find Logitech HID devices
devices = hid.HidDeviceFilter(vendor_id=vendor_id).get_devices()

if not devices:
    print("No Logitech device found.")
    exit()

# Select the device
device = devices[0] if len(devices) == 1 else None
if not device:
    print("Multiple Logitech devices found. Please select one:")
    for i, dev in enumerate(devices):
        print(f"{i}: {dev.product_name} (Product ID: {dev.product_id:04X})")
    selection = int(input("\nEnter the number of the device to select (0-{}): ".format(len(devices) - 1)))
    device = devices[selection]
else:
    print(f"Automatically selected device: {device.product_name}")

# Open the device and set the data handler
try:
    device.open()
    device.set_raw_data_handler(sample_handler)
    print("Waiting for data... Press any key to stop.")
    while not kbhit() and device.is_plugged():
        sleep(0.5)
finally:
    device.close()


Questions:

How can I correctly interpret the X and Y axis values from the raw data I receive?
Are there alternative methods for reading joystick input in Python besides using the inputs library?
I've heard about using HID descriptors to understand joystick control values. How can I use HID descriptors to achieve this?

HID Descriptors:
USB Input Device

Connection Status   Device connected
Current Configuration   1
Speed   Full
Device Address  3
Number Of Open Pipes    1
Device Descriptor Extreme 3D pro
Offset  Field   Size    Value   Description
0   bLength 1   12h 
1   bDescriptorType 1   01h Device
2   bcdUSB  2   0200h   USB Spec 2.0
4   bDeviceClass    1   00h Class info in Ifc Descriptors
5   bDeviceSubClass 1   00h 
6   bDeviceProtocol 1   00h 
7   bMaxPacketSize0 1   08h 8 bytes
8   idVendor    2   046Dh   Logitech, Inc.
10  idProduct   2   C215h   
12  bcdDevice   2   5711h   57.11
14  iManufacturer   1   01h "Logitech"
15  iProduct    1   02h "Extreme 3D pro"
16  iSerialNumber   1   03h "00000000002A"
17  bNumConfigurations  1   01h 
Configuration Descriptor 1 Bus Powered, 100 mA
Offset  Field   Size    Value   Description
0   bLength 1   09h 
1   bDescriptorType 1   02h Configuration
2   wTotalLength    2   0022h   
4   bNumInterfaces  1   01h 
5   bConfigurationValue 1   01h 
6   iConfiguration  1   04h "HID Config"
7   bmAttributes    1   80h Bus Powered
4..0: Reserved      ...00000    
5: Remote Wakeup        ..0.....    No
6: Self Powered     .0......    No, Bus Powered
7: Reserved (set to one)
(bus-powered for 1.0)       1.......    
8   bMaxPower   1   32h 100 mA
Interface Descriptor 0/0 HID, 1 Endpoint
Offset  Field   Size    Value   Description
0   bLength 1   09h 
1   bDescriptorType 1   04h Interface
2   bInterfaceNumber    1   00h 
3   bAlternateSetting   1   00h 
4   bNumEndpoints   1   01h 
5   bInterfaceClass 1   03h HID
6   bInterfaceSubClass  1   01h Boot Interface
7   bInterfaceProtocol  1   00h 
8   iInterface  1   00h 
HID Descriptor
Offset  Field   Size    Value   Description
0   bLength 1   09h 
1   bDescriptorType 1   21h HID
2   bcdHID  2   0111h   1.11
4   bCountryCode    1   00h 
5   bNumDescriptors 1   01h 
6   bDescriptorType 1   22h Report
7   wDescriptorLength   2   007Ah   122 bytes
Endpoint Descriptor 81 1 In, Interrupt, 1 ms
Offset  Field   Size    Value   Description
0   bLength 1   07h 
1   bDescriptorType 1   05h Endpoint
2   bEndpointAddress    1   81h 1 In
3   bmAttributes    1   03h Interrupt
1..0: Transfer Type     ......11    Interrupt
7..2: Reserved      000000..    
4   wMaxPacketSize  2   0007h   7 bytes
6   bInterval   1   01h 1 ms
Interface 0 HID Report Descriptor Joystick
Item Tag (Value)    Raw Data
Usage Page (Generic Desktop)    05 01 
Usage (Joystick)    09 04 
Collection (Application)    A1 01 
    Collection (Logical)    A1 02 
        Report Count (2)    95 02 
        Report Size (10)    75 0A 
        Logical Minimum (0) 15 00 
        Logical Maximum (1023)  26 FF 03 
        Physical Minimum (0)    35 00 
        Physical Maximum (1023) 46 FF 03 
        Usage (X)   09 30 
        Usage (Y)   09 31 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02 
        Report Size (4) 75 04 
        Report Count (1)    95 01 
        Logical Maximum (7) 25 07 
        Physical Maximum (315)  46 3B 01 
        Unit (Eng Rot: Degree)  66 14 00 
        Usage (Hat Switch)  09 39 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,Null,Bit) 81 42 
        Unit (None) 65 00 
        Report Size (8) 75 08 
        Logical Maximum (255)   26 FF 00 
        Physical Maximum (255)  46 FF 00 
        Usage (Rz)  09 35 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02 
        Push    A4 
        Report Count (8)    95 08 
        Report Size (1) 75 01 
        Logical Maximum (1) 25 01 
        Physical Maximum (1)    45 01 
        Usage Page (Button) 05 09 
        Usage Minimum (Button 1)    19 01 
        Usage Maximum (Button 8)    29 08 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02 
        Pop B4 
        Usage (Slider)  09 36 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02 
        Report Count (4)    95 04 
        Report Size (1) 75 01 
        Logical Maximum (1) 25 01 
        Physical Maximum (1)    45 01 
        Usage Page (Button) 05 09 
        Usage Minimum (Button 9)    19 09 
        Usage Maximum (Button 12)   29 0C 
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02 
        Report Count (4)    95 04 
        Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs)    81 01 
    End Collection  C0 
    Collection (Logical)    A1 02 
        Report Count (4)    95 04 
        Report Size (8) 75 08 
        Logical Maximum (255)   26 FF 00 
        Physical Maximum (255)  46 FF 00 
        Usage Page (Vendor-Defined 1)   06 00 FF 
        Usage (Vendor-Defined 1)    09 01 
        Feature (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit)  B1 02 
    End Collection  C0 
End Collection

Additional Information:
I know libraries like pywinusb.hid, but I want to explore other options if possible.
Any guidance on creating a program to parse and interpret joystick values using HID descriptors automatically would also be appreciated.

Hello, have your tried looking for this joystick's documentation? I find it weird that your joystick supposed X, Y value to be around 2 and 4... A joystick like this one is supposedly made to get higher levels of precision, I'd expect values in the hundreds for even a slight movement. PS2 joysticks have ranges between 0 and 1023, with 511, in the middle, being the neutral point. TL;DR Find the documentation

I guess 2 and 4 could be digital joystick values (like you'd have on e.g. a NES gamepad).

No I can't find the document. I sure and I manually check it data Index  3 to 7 I have check it every thinks work good I mention in above picture are same . Only x and y I facing a issue.

I have found a package called Pygame which is used to easily read remote data. It automatically reads the HID descriptor to determine the number of buttons and analogue controls.
Using the Pygame package is a good solution for this issue.

You can decode the HID Report Descriptor with https://github.com/abend0c1/hidrdd and it will generate C headers for each of the reports that the device supports.
Just cut/paste the HID Report Descriptor from your Wireshark capture into say my.rd, and run
rexx rd.rex my.rd

When I ran it, it produced the following:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 04        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010004 Joystick (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010004: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Joystick, Type=Application Collection)
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x0: Page=, Usage=, Type=) <-- Error: COLLECTION must be preceded by a known USAGE <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CL (Logical Collection)
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
75 0A            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x0A (10) Number of bits per field  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF03          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x03FF (1023)  
35 00            (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MINIMUM   0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 35 00 with 34
46 FF03          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x03FF (1023)  
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 10 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
75 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x04 (4) Number of bits per field  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
25 07            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x07 (7)  
46 3B01          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x013B (315)  
66 1400          (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x0014 Rotation in degrees [1° units] (4=System=English Rotation, 1=Rotation=Degrees)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 66 1400 with 65 14
09 39            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010039 Hat Switch (Dynamic Value)  
81 42            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000042 (1 field x 4 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 1=Null 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
65 00            (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x00 No unit (0=None)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 65 00 with 64
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
26 FF00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255)  
46 FF00          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x00FF (255)  
09 35            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010035 Rz (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
A4               (GLOBAL) PUSH               USAGE_PAGE=0x0001 LOGICAL(MIN=0,MAX=255) PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=255) UNIT(0x00000000,EXP=0) REPORT(ID=0x,SIZE=8,COUNT=1)
95 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x08 (8) Number of fields  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
45 01            (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x01 (1)  
05 09            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
29 08            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090008 Button 8 (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (8 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
B4               (GLOBAL) POP                USAGE_PAGE=0x0001 LOGICAL(MIN=0,MAX=255) PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=255) UNIT(0x00000000,EXP=0) REPORT(ID=0x,SIZE=8,COUNT=1) 
09 36            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010036 Slider (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
45 01            (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x01 (1)  
05 09            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 09            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090009 Button 9 (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
29 0C            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x0009000C Button 12 (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (4 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 4 
81 01            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000001 (4 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical  <-- Warning: Physical units are still in effect PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=1) UNIT(0x00000000,EXP=0)
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x0: Page=, Usage=, Type=) <-- Error: COLLECTION must be preceded by a known USAGE <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CL (Logical Collection)
95 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 4 
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
26 FF00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255)  
46 FF00          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x00FF (255)  
06 00FF          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF00 Vendor-defined 
09 01            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage (document it by inserting 0001 into file FF00.conf)
B1 02            (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000002 (4 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical  <-- Warning: Physical units are still in effect PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=255) UNIT(0x00000000,EXP=0)
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application  <-- Warning: Physical units are still in effect PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=255) UNIT(0x00000000,EXP=0)
*/

// All structure fields should be byte-aligned...
#pragma pack(push,1)

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined featureReport (Device <-> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: CA:Joystick CL:
  uint8_t  VEN_Joystick0001[4];                      // Usage 0xFF000001: , Value = 0 to 255, Physical = Value
} featureReport_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic Desktop Page inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: CA:Joystick CL:
  uint16_t GD_JoystickX : 10;                        // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 1023, Physical = Value
  uint16_t GD_JoystickY : 10;                        // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 1023, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  GD_JoystickHatSwitch : 4;                 // Usage 0x00010039: Hat Switch, Value = 0 to 7, Physical = Value x 45 in degrees
  uint8_t  GD_JoystickRz;                            // Usage 0x00010035: Rz, Value = 0 to 255, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton1 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton2 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton3 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton4 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090004: Button 4, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton5 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090005: Button 5, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton6 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090006: Button 6, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton7 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090007: Button 7, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton8 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090008: Button 8, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  GD_JoystickSlider;                        // Usage 0x00010036: Slider, Value = 0 to 255, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton9 : 1;                  // Usage 0x00090009: Button 9, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton10 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000A: Button 10, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton11 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000B: Button 11, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  BTN_JoystickButton12 : 1;                 // Usage 0x0009000C: Button 12, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport_t;

#pragma pack(pop)

Logitech seems to have misused the PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM item but that doesn't affect the report layouts.

Thanks aja, should I decode the raw data also ? Do you have any idea how can I read joystick data, any reference available

You'll need to split each report into python variables which shouldn't be difficult for a python wizz (which I am not). Logitech have made that more difficult than strictly necessary because in this case the fields do not align on byte boundaries - i.e. 10 bits, 10 bits, 4 bits, 8 bits etc.

I'm developing an application using Qt5 and am open to using either C++ or C. I am having trouble reading the X and Y joystick values while other joystick buttons and options are working fine. I have explored various Python references, but they haven't been successful. Could you provide any references or solutions for reading joystick values in C++ or C.

In windows game controller I have checking all button and especially X and y joystick controls are working well.
